# Multiple USB cameras simultaneously - labview

Tags: image-processing, labview

I am quite new to Labview. Does anyone know how to get images from 2 usb cameras simultaneously. There are some topics about it in the internet, but all of them are a little bit misleading and do not present the whole solution.

Comment: This is a very open question please specify more and show what you have done. The simple answer is just get the images in a synchronized timed loop. The actual answer is depending on you cameras and what you call simultaneously. What is the manufacturer and type of camera. Do you have the labview vision acquisition library. Do you have a hardware trigger or do you rely on software triggering. With software triggering images will not be taken at exactly the same moment. What is you actually problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something supported using basic LabVIEW funtions.

However, you can use hooks into the User32.dll to create windows and populate them with live images from USB webcams.

I've had [**the example posted here**](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/multiple-USB-cameras-in-Labview/m-p/833517) working on LabVIEW 2016 + 2018

The linked example is displaying 2 webcams and doesn't need IMAQ drivers to run

Answer (score 0):

use labview 2014 and higher also check if your cpu and RAM of your system could support two or more simountensous camera .you can check this by open two camera in same time but with different software after that you find out that you system could handle two camera 
use Imaqdx for open camera but it is better to use flat sequence for config and open part 
it is better open camera by one by but you can capture in same time inside while loop 
if you system could not handle two camera told me I could suggest a method to solve it